# SAP Cloud Platform. Fiori Mobile Hybrid Application : Offline oDATA documentaton?

Tags: odata, sapui5, offline, offlineapps

I'm struggling to find any clear or coherent documentation on implementing offline oData through SCP Fiori Mobile.

The best info I've came across has been to add the following to Manifest.json here :

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/22/make-offline-app-using-sap-cp-mobile-service-for-sap-fiori-part-1/

Is there any other documentation out there?

```
   "sap.mobile": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "definingRequests": {},
        "stores": [
            {
                "name": "CategorySet",
                "serviceRoot": "/SAPUI5-ABAP-SFI/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSV_SURVEY_SRV/",
                "definingRequests": {
                    "CategorySet": "/CategorySet"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.